# Value doesn't live long enough, despite being constrained to

Tags: compiler-errors, closures, rust, lifetime

The following Rust code fails to compile:

```
pub struct UserAction<'u> {
    _act: &'u mut (FnMut() + 'u)
}

impl<'u, F: FnMut() + 'u> From<F> for UserAction<'u> {
    fn from(f: F) -> Self {
        UserAction { _act: (&mut f) as &'u mut (FnMut() + 'u) }
    }
}
```

The error I get from `rustc` 1.10 stable is:

```
lives.rs:7:38: 7:39 error: `f` does not live long enough
lives.rs:7             UserAction { _act: (&mut f) as &'u mut (FnMut() + 'u) }
                                                ^
lives.rs:6:31: 8:10 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'u as defined on the block at 6:30...
lives.rs:6         fn from(f: F) -> Self {
                                         ^
lives.rs:6:31: 8:10 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the scope of function body at 6:30
lives.rs:6         fn from(f: F) -> Self {
                                         ^
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm not sure why this is an error; the type `F` lives at least as long as the lifetime `'u`, because it's constrained to.  What am I missing, and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [mcarton says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339915/155423), you are passing ownership of the closure into the function, then attempting to take a reference to it. Rejoice that the compiler caught the mistake and prevented you from using a reference to some out-of-scope variable that would cause memory corruption.

The restriction `F: FnMut() + 'u` states that `F` must be a type that implements the `FnMut` trait and **contains references** that outlive the lifetime `'u`. It does not say that `F` itself must outlive that lifetime. In fact, we can see that `f` has no owner after the method exits, so its lifetime ends then - thus the error.

The most direct equivalent that should work is to use a *boxed trait object* instead of a *trait object reference*:

```
pub struct UserAction<'u> {
    _act: Box<FnMut() + 'u>,
}

impl<'u, F: FnMut() + 'u> From<F> for UserAction<'u> {
    fn from(f: F) -> Self {
        UserAction { _act: Box::new(f) }
    }
}
```

Another alternate is to percolate the generic type:

```
pub struct UserAction<F> {
    _act: F,
}

impl<F: FnMut()> From<F> for UserAction<F> {
    fn from(f: F) -> Self {
        UserAction { _act: f }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up going with the `Box`-based approach.

Answer (score 2):

`f` is local to that `from` method so are all references to it.
What you want is:

```
pub struct UserAction<'u> {
    _act: &'u mut (FnMut() + 'u)
}

impl<'u, F: FnMut() + 'u> From<&'u mut F> for UserAction<'u> {
//                             ^^^^^^^
    fn from(f: &'u mut F) -> Self {
//             ^^^^^^^
        UserAction { _act: f as &'u mut (FnMut() + 'u) }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this compiles, I now can't use it at all.  The expression `Self::from(&mut || {})` causes the error "borrowed value does not live long enough".

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame you could do that if you place the closure in a variable that lasts longer than the result of `Self::from` - that would allow the reference to be valid long enough.